# Multiple Bipartite Entangled State in Cirq

Tags: programming, quantum-state, entanglement, cirq

I am trying to create this state:
rho =  = q . rho_{1,2} + r . rho_{2,3} + s . rho{1,3} + (1-q-r-s) . rho_separable

And I wrote this code:

```
   import random
import numpy as np
import cirq

circuit, circuit2, circuit3   = cirq.Circuit()
p = 0.2
q = 0.1
r = 0.3
alice, bob, charlie = cirq.LineQubit.range(1, 4)
rho_12 = circuit.append([cirq.H(alice), cirq.CNOT(alice, bob)]) 
#circuit.append([cirq.H(alice), cirq.CNOT(alice, bob)]) 
rho_23 = circuit.append([cirq.H(bob), cirq.CNOT(bob, charlie)]) 
rho_13 = circuit.append([cirq.H(alice), cirq.CNOT(alice, charlie)]) 
circuit = rho_12 + rho_23 + rho_13
print(circuit)
```

In here I have 2 problem:

1)This line is not working: `circuit = rho_12 + rho_23 + rho_13`

2)I cannot multiply the state with p or q or r. What I mean is that I can't write this line:

```
rho_12 = circuit.append([cirq.H(alice), cirq.CNOT(alice, bob)]) * q
```

Could you please show me how I can write this state?

Comment: append doesn't return anything, it adds into the circuit. Your circuit is in the `circuit` variable already; no need to add those things together.

Comment: oh thank you very much and what about multiplying q or r or p. I can not write that: rho_12 = circuit.append([cirq.H(alice), cirq.CNOT(alice, bob)]) * q @CraigGidney

Comment: You can multiply circuits like `multiplied_circuit = cirq.Circuit(op1, op2) * 3`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the amswer but I want to multiply float number, we can think it like noise so with float number I cannot multiply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to think `append` is returning a circuit, instead of modifying the circuit you called it on. `circuit.append(op)` doesn't return anything, it adds an operation to `circuit`.

```
alice, bob, charlie = cirq.LineQubit.range(1, 4)
circuit = cirq.Circuit()
circuit.append([cirq.H(alice), cirq.CNOT(alice, bob)])
circuit.append([cirq.H(bob), cirq.CNOT(bob, charlie)]) 
...
```

Alternatively, you can make a new circuit for each of the pieces and then add them together:

```
rho_12 = cirq.Circuit(
    cirq.H(alice),
    cirq.CNOT(alice, bob),
)
...
circuit = rho_12 + rho_23 + rho_13
```

Comment: Many thanks :) A small question: I wrote the same thing for ghz state too but I have a  syntax error and I could not find. Maybe you can see can you have a look? ghz = cirq.Circuit(  
   cirq.H(qubits[0]),
   for i in range (n-1):
       cirq.CNOT ( qubits [i] , qubits [i+1]),
   cirq.measure (* qubits , key ='x'), 
   cirq.final_density_matrix(circuit),
)