# Cirq-Measuring a State with Rotation Matrix

Tags: programming, quantum-state, entanglement, measurement, cirq

I have this state:
$$p |\text{GHZ}\rangle \langle \text{GHZ}| + (1-p)\rho$$
And after creating this state I have this code lines:

```
state = p * GHZ+(1-p)* rho
state = p * GHZ + (1 - p) * rho
print(f"final state: \n {state}")
print(cirq.sample_density_matrix(state, indices=[0, 1, 2], repetitions=10))
```

Now I want to measure this state. I know we have `cirq.measure` in Cirq But I don't know which kind of measurement is used by this function (and the last line is also doing measurement if I am not wrong??)

```
cirq.measure(a, b, c)
```

I have 3 questions

1. I want to use rotation matrix and measure my state. Do we have rotation matrix in Cirq. Can you please show me how can I measure my state with rotation matrix in Cirq?
2. I want to choose x and Y randomly and I want to do measurement
3. Which kind of measurement is used by Cirq.measure() and (cirq.sample_density_matrix(state, indices=[0, 1, 2], repetitions=10))

   cirq.measure(a, b, c)
   (cirq.sample_density_matrix(state, indices=[0, 1, 2], repetitions=10))

Best and thanks

Comment: what is meant by GHZ

Comment: This is ordinary GHZ state which is created by H gate and CNOT gate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `cirq.rx` `ry`, `rz` exist for rotation around X, Y and Z axes on the Bloch sphere
2. If you have to measure in non-computational bases, you will have to do the rotations yourself. In my answer to [previous your question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14288/bit-flip-seperable-state-and-several-question-about-cirq) I wrote two versions: one with density matrices the other one with `cirq.Circuit`.

   - In case of the circuit model you can use `circuit.append(cirq.rx(np.pi/3)(a))` for example before the measurement, where `a` is the first qubit.
   - in case of the density matrix you'll have to calculate the tensored unitaries with `cirq.kron` and `cirq.unitary` and then multiply the density as usual: `unitary @ density_matrix @ unitary.conj().T`. For example:

   ```
     # this is rx(pi/3) ⊗ I ⊗ I - the first qubit gets rotated, the other
     # two remains the same
     u = cirq.kron(cirq.unitary(cirq.rx(np.pi/3)), np.eye(2), np.eye(2))
     # this applies the unitary evolution on the state density matrix 
     rotated_state = u @ state @ u.conj().T
   ```
3. `cirq.measure` measures in the computational basis. `cirq.sample_density_matrix` samples in the computational basis repeatedly see [reference docs](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/cirq.sample_density_matrix.html) - it simulates "preparing the state and measuring it" multiple times. If you want the state after the measurement then probably `cirq.measure_density_matrix` is better suited.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could not understand the part of density matrix. Multiply means multiplying ghz part and rho part or multiplay with tensor and unitary part. And after that how can I define angle for rotation matrix?(like the circuit part)

Comment: And for the circuit part,you wrote a. Does a correspond şubat aor the state?

Comment: I clarified my points please take a look

Comment: Hello I used x and y for rotation  `state = p * GHZ + (1 - p) * rho

print(f"final state: \n {state}")

print(cirq.sample_density_matrix(state, indices=[0, 1, 2], repetitions=10))

u = cirq.kron(cirq.unitary(cirq.rx(np.pi/3)), np.eye(2), np.eye(2))
  # this applies the unitary evolution on the state density matrix 
u2 = cirq.kron(cirq.unitary(cirq.ry(np.pi/3)), np.eye(2), np.eye(2))dss
rotated_state = u @ u2 @ state @ u.conj().T
print(rotated_state)
print (cirq.measure_density_matrix(rotated_state,indices=[0, 1, 2]))`  After rotating state should I measure again?

Comment: I used two direction for rotation x and y and after rotation should I use `cirq.measure_density_matrix(rotated_state,indices=[0, 1, 2])`

Comment: And last question is that here is the image of my result https://ibb.co/3sByX2B  The thing is that I could understand that first parenthesis is for my qubits are like 1 0 0 (a b c) and after that I could not understand the results/list. We have something like that  array([[0.       +0.j       , 0.       +0.j       , 0.       +0.j       ,
        0.       +0.j       , 0.       +0.j       , 0.       +0.j       ,
        0.       +0.j       , 0.       +0.j       ], and before the array we have "[" and then we have 8 results then the parenthesis is closing. What does it mean?  @ Balint Pato

Comment: The array is the density matrix itself. It's an 8-by-8 (8=$2^3$ because of the three qubits!) [numpy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). Whether you need measurement: really depends on what you want to do. Can you provide a better description of what you want to achieve? Are you reproducing a paper? Are you solving a homework exercise? In case yes, can you point to the original spec? Or are you just experimenting yourself? Then what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh Ok, before the measuring I gave 10 repetation and I expected I should see an array with 10 element but I just forgat the function(density matrix) which I used in the code becquse apart from this code I have 11 different code too and I am looking all of them at the same time..  This is related to my thesis

Comment: Got it :) Thanks for using Cirq for your thesis!

Comment: Thanks :) @Balint Pato . For the non computational basis after I wrote this code line `rotated_state = u @ state @ u.conj().T` Should I use measure function in Cirq like: cirq.measure_density_matrix or after rotation everythin is ok and I don't need to use any fuction again ? I am asking that because cirq.measure_density_matrix measures  for computational basis and after rotaion matrix usong cirq.measure_density_matrix is a bit weird I guess

Comment: If you want measurement statistics of a U unitary in a computational basis you do "apply U and then measure in computational basis". If you want to measure in non-computational basis, but you only can measure in computational basis, that means "apply U then rotate then measure in computational basis". So, you have to `cirq.meausre_density_matrix` and only after the rotation (not before it). The rotation rotates the frame of reference _before_ the measurement. After the measurement it only rotates the collapsed state which I don't think is what you want.